# can we contract "The dog across the street is big." to "The dog across the street's big."?

Tags: contractions

can we contract "**The dog across the street is big.**" to "**The dog across the street's big.**"?

I think we can't because I felt weird  when saying "**The dog across the street's big.**"

Comment: @user3169 - from the page you linked to: "A contraction is a shortened version of the written and spoken forms of a word, syllable, *or word group,* created by omission of internal letters and sounds." So with that in mind, how is "street's" not a contraction of "street is"? I hear [noun] is [adjective] shortened to [noun]'s [adjective] quite frequently. (Much less common to see it written.)

Comment: It's perfectly okay.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, at least informally and in certain dialects, if we can contract *is* to *'s* and append it to a noun, we can do it to a [noun phrase](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/noun-phrase) too.  For example,

> [The diner across the street's still open.](https://books.google.com/books?id=VgpXBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT202&dq=%22across%20the%20street%27s%22&pg=PT202#v=onepage&q=%22across%20the%20street%27s%22&f=false)
>
> [You ain't kiddin', not if that mug shot I saw's any indication.](https://books.google.com/books?id=h1MnBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT150&dq=%22I%20saw's%22&pg=PT150#v=onepage&q=%22I%20saw's%22&f=false)
>
> [The little bastard movie I made's got a life of its own.](https://books.google.com/books?id=rSMkCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA219&dq=%22i%20made's%22&pg=PA219#v=onepage&q=%22i%20made's%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

We use the contraction of **is** to **'s** with pronouns or simple nouns, but not with noun phrases. These are ok:

> That's big!
>
> The dog's big!

We would not normally use this contraction with a noun phrase like **the dog across the street**: we want to put a pause after the noun phrase, to make it clear that we have reached the end of of the noun phrase:

> The dog across the street- is big.
>
> The man that you met yesterday- is my neighbour.

Comment: This may be a dialect issue, but in my dialect (NYC English), this sort of 's at the end of a phrase is not at all unusual.  For example "[The diner across the street's still open](https://books.google.com/books?id=VgpXBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT202&dq=%22across%20the%20street's%22&pg=PT202#v=onepage&q=%22across%20the%20street's%22&f=false)" sounds completely natural.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

And here's an interesting example from a contemporary novel:

> Whatever Mum’s saying’s drowned out by the grimy roar of the bus pulling away

(Opening clause of *[Slade House](http://www.randomhouse.com/highschool/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9780812998696&view=printexcerpt))*

*Whatever Mum's saying* is a noun phrase, and the English novelist David Mitchell has used a contraction after *saying* to get

> Whatever Mum's saying's...

in the passive construction *is drowned out*.

This is simple narrative prose.

What calls attention to this clause is the double contraction in the noun phrase: the first one (Mum's) represents the *'s* of the progressive  *is saying*.

It represents natural English narrative, which is characterized by contractions (*I've got*, *he'll do it*, *She's the one*, *Mum's the word*, *David's buying the dog's not gonna go over well with dad*, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it sounds that awkward, but you can't really do that in standard English. If you were a fiction writer and you were experimenting with form, you could have a narrator or character who talks like that:

> "The dog-across-the-street's big," said the boy.

Or even just:

> "The dog across the street's big," said the boy.

In more formal English, you'd probably want to say something like:

> The dog across the street is big.

Or if you really want to use a contraction for a particular reason:

> The dog's big, the one across the street.